# React: Get a specific property from a generic respone

Tags: reactjs, generics

I am working on an existing project which renders a checkbox which gets item lists from different services, each service returns different type, But the main function which handles it gets it as a generic type T

I know that all the types from the services has a common property called "title", but I cannot it from the main function because it gets only T as input, which can be any object.

How can I define define the generic T to include title property?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).

If your generic `T` type will always include a string title property for example and you have something like `type TCheckboxProps<T> = {...}` you could write something like

```
type TCheckboxProps<T> = {
  ...
  item: {title: string} & T,
  ...
}
```